# Schedule Firebase Function with Axios - axios firebase function Error: Request failed with status code 500

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, axios, google-cloud-functions

My scheduled Firebase Cloud Function appears to be returning a generic 500 error when trying to make an external API call using Axios. I have verified that the endpoint works in Postman.

Here's the code:

```
const admin = require("firebase-admin");
const axios = require("axios");
const functions = require("firebase-functions");

exports.scheduledFunction = functions.pubsub
    .schedule("every 24 hours")
    .timeZone("America/New_York")
    .onRun(async (context) => {
      try {
        const db = admin.firestore();
        const querySnapshot = await
        db.collection("collectionName").get();
        const promises = querySnapshot.docs.map((doc) =>
          db.collection("collectionName").doc(doc.id).delete());

        await Promise.all(promises);

        const options = {
          method: "get",
          url: "***",
          timeout: 500000000,
          headers: {
            "Content-Type": "application/json",
          },
        };

        const axiosResponse = await axios(options);
        const apiResponse = axiosResponse.data;
        console.log("apiResponse = " + apiResponse);
        const parsedResponse = apiResponse["organic"];
        const docCreationPromises = parsedResponse
            .map((resObj) => db.collection("collectionName").add(resObj));
        await Promise.all(docCreationPromises);
        console.log(parsedResponse);
        return null;
      } catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
        return null;
      }
    });
```

parsedResponse["organic"] returns ab array of objects in postman, "organic" being the array name. I simply want to write each nested object to Firestore as it's own Document.

Error Log in GCP:

```
    Error: Request failed with status code 500
        at createError (/workspace/node_modules/axios/lib/core/createError.js:16:15)
        at settle (/workspace/node_modules/axios/lib/core/settle.js:17:12)
        at IncomingMessage.handleStreamEnd (/workspace/node_modules/axios/lib/adapters/http.js:312:11)
        at IncomingMessage.emit (node:events:402:35)
        at IncomingMessage.emit (node:domain:537:15)
        at endReadableNT (node:internal/streams/readable:1343:12)
        at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:83:21) {
      config: {
        transitional: {
          silentJSONParsing: true,
          forcedJSONParsing: true,
          clarifyTimeoutError: false
        },
        adapter: [Function: httpAdapter],
        transformRequest: [ [Function: transformRequest] ],
        transformResponse: [ [Function: transformResponse] ],
        timeout: 500000000,
        xsrfCookieName: 'XSRF-TOKEN',
        xsrfHeaderName: 'X-XSRF-TOKEN',
        maxContentLength: -1,
        maxBodyLength: -1,
        validateStatus: [Function: validateStatus],
        headers: {
          Accept: 'application/json, text/plain, */*',
          'Content-Type': 'application/json',
          'User-Agent': 'axios/0.25.0'
        },
        method: 'get',
        url: 'https://app.zenserp.com/api/v2/search?apikey=xxxxcda&q=Microsoft&location=10006,New%York,United%States&hl=en',
        data: undefined
      },
      request: <ref *1> ClientRequest {
        _events: [Object: null prototype] {
          abort: [Function (anonymous)],
          aborted: [Function (anonymous)],
          connect: [Function (anonymous)],
          error: [Function (anonymous)],
          socket: [Function (anonymous)],
          timeout: [Function (anonymous)],
          prefinish: [Function: requestOnPrefinish]
        },
        _eventsCount: 7,
        _maxListeners: undefined,
        outputData: [],
        outputSize: 0,
        writable: true,
        destroyed: false,
        _last: true,
        chunkedEncoding: false,
        shouldKeepAlive: false,
        maxRequestsOnConnectionReached: false,
        _defaultKeepAlive: true,
        useChunkedEncodingByDefault: false,
        sendDate: false,
        _removedConnection: false,
        _removedContLen: false,
        _removedTE: false,
        _contentLength: 0,
        _hasBody: true,
        _trailer: '',
        finished: true,
        _headerSent: true,
        _closed: false,
        socket: TLSSocket {
          _tlsOptions: [Object],
          _secureEstablished: true,
          _securePending: false,
          _newSessionPending: false,
          _controlReleased: true,
          secureConnecting: false,
          _SNICallback: null,
          servername: 'app.zenserp.com',
          alpnProtocol: false,
          authorized: true,
          authorizationError: null,
          encrypted: true,
          _events: [Object: null prototype],
          _eventsCount: 10,
          connecting: false,
          _hadError: false,
          _parent: null,
          _host: 'app.zenserp.com',
          _readableState: [ReadableState],
          _maxListeners: undefined,
          _writableState: [WritableState],
          allowHalfOpen: false,
          _sockname: null,
          _pendingData: null,
          _pendingEncoding: '',
          server: undefined,
          _server: null,
          ssl: [TLSWrap],
          _requestCert: true,
          _rejectUnauthorized: true,
          parser: null,
          _httpMessage: [Circular *1],
          timeout: 500000000,
          [Symbol(res)]: [TLSWrap],
          [Symbol(verified)]: true,
          [Symbol(pendingSession)]: null,
          [Symbol(async_id_symbol)]: 428,
          [Symbol(kHandle)]: [TLSWrap],
          [Symbol(kSetNoDelay)]: false,
          [Symbol(lastWriteQueueSize)]: 0,
          [Symbol(timeout)]: Timeout {
            _idleTimeout: 500000000,
            _idlePrev: [TimersList],
            _idleNext: [TimersList],
            _idleStart: 1935,
            _onTimeout: [Function: bound ],
            _timerArgs: undefined,
            _repeat: null,
            _destroyed: false,
            [Symbol(refed)]: false,
            [Symbol(kHasPrimitive)]: false,
            [Symbol(asyncId)]: 442,
            [Symbol(triggerId)]: 431
          },
          [Symbol(kBuffer)]: null,
          [Symbol(kBufferCb)]: null,
          [Symbol(kBufferGen)]: null,
          [Symbol(kCapture)]: false,
          [Symbol(kBytesRead)]: 0,
          [Symbol(kBytesWritten)]: 0,
          [Symbol(connect-options)]: [Object],
          [Symbol(RequestTimeout)]: undefined
        },
        _header: 'GET /api/v2/search?apikey=xxxa&q=Microsoft&location=10006,New%York,United%States&hl=en HTTP/1.1\r\n' +
          'Accept: application/json, text/plain, */*\r\n' +
          'Content-Type: application/json\r\n' +
          'User-Agent: axios/0.25.0\r\n' +
          'Host: app.zenserp.com\r\n' +
          'Connection: close\r\n' +
          '\r\n',
        _keepAliveTimeout: 0,
        _onPendingData: [Function: nop],
        agent: Agent {
          _events: [Object: null prototype],
          _eventsCount: 2,
          _maxListeners: undefined,
          defaultPort: 443,
          protocol: 'https:',
          options: [Object: null prototype],
          requests: [Object: null prototype] {},
          sockets: [Object: null prototype],
          freeSockets: [Object: null prototype] {},
          keepAliveMsecs: 1000,
          keepAlive: false,
          maxSockets: Infinity,
          maxFreeSockets: 256,
          scheduling: 'lifo',
          maxTotalSockets: Infinity,
          totalSocketCount: 1,
          maxCachedSessions: 100,
          _sessionCache: [Object],
          [Symbol(kCapture)]: false
        },
        socketPath: undefined,
        method: 'GET',
        maxHeaderSize: undefined,
        insecureHTTPParser: undefined,
        path: '/api/v2/search?apikey=xxxxx&q=Microsoft&location=10006,New%York,United%States&hl=en',
        _ended: true,
        res: IncomingMessage {
          _readableState: [ReadableState],
          _events: [Object: null prototype],
          _eventsCount: 4,
          _maxListeners: undefined,
          socket: [TLSSocket],
          httpVersionMajor: 1,
          httpVersionMinor: 1,
          httpVersion: '1.1',
          complete: true,
          rawHeaders: [Array],
          rawTrailers: [],
          aborted: false,
          upgrade: false,
          url: '',
          method: null,
          statusCode: 500,
          statusMessage: 'Internal Server Error',
          client: [TLSSocket],
          _consuming: true,
          _dumped: false,
          req: [Circular *1],
          responseUrl: 'https://app.zenserp.com/api/v2/search?apikey=xxxxxxxxx
&q=Microsoft&location=10006,New%York,United%States&hl=en',
          redirects: [],
          [Symbol(kCapture)]: false,
          [Symbol(kHeaders)]: [Object],
          [Symbol(kHeadersCount)]: 40,
          [Symbol(kTrailers)]: null,
          [Symbol(kTrailersCount)]: 0,
          [Symbol(RequestTimeout)]: undefined
        },
        aborted: false,
        timeoutCb: null,
        upgradeOrConnect: false,
        parser: null,
        maxHeadersCount: null,
        reusedSocket: false,
        host: 'app.zenserp.com',
        protocol: 'https:',
        _redirectable: Writable {
          _writableState: [WritableState],
          _events: [Object: null prototype],
          _eventsCount: 3,
          _maxListeners: undefined,
          _options: [Object],
          _ended: true,
          _ending: true,
          _redirectCount: 0,
          _redirects: [],
          _requestBodyLength: 0,
          _requestBodyBuffers: [],
          _onNativeResponse: [Function (anonymous)],
          _currentRequest: [Circular *1],
          _currentUrl: 'https://app.zenserp.com/api/v2/search?apikey=xxxxx&q=Microsoft&location=10006,New%York,United%States&hl=en',
          _timeout: null,
          [Symbol(kCapture)]: false
        },
        [Symbol(kCapture)]: false,
        [Symbol(kNeedDrain)]: false,
        [Symbol(corked)]: 0,
        [Symbol(kOutHeaders)]: [Object: null prototype] {
          accept: [Array],
          'content-type': [Array],
          'user-agent': [Array],
          host: [Array]
        }
      },
      response: {
        status: 500,
        statusText: 'Internal Server Error',
        headers: {
          date: 'Fri, 18 Feb 2022 17:58:04 GMT',
          'content-type': 'application/json',
          'transfer-encoding': 'chunked',
          connection: 'close',
          'cache-control': 'private, must-revalidate',
          'x-ratelimit-remaining': '44',
          pragma: 'no-cache',
          expires: '-1',
          'x-robots-tag': 'noindex',
          'access-control-allow-origin': '*',
          'access-control-allow-methods': 'GET, POST, OPTIONS',
          'access-control-allow-headers': 'DNT,User-Agent,X-Requested-With,If-Modified-Since,Cache-Control,Content-Type,Range',
          'access-control-expose-headers': 'Content-Length,Content-Range',
          'cf-cache-status': 'DYNAMIC',
          'expect-ct': 'max-age=604800, report-uri="https://report-uri.cloudflare.com/cdn-cgi/beacon/expect-ct"',
          'report-to': '{"endpoints":[{"url":"https:\\/\\/a.nel.cloudflare.com\\/report\\/v3?s=HkcTgEPFZ5LTRZv6i%2BfVRyZ%2BEoMKz6aNIQOc4us%2Fg1GAsUJBm4LdtRJI%2BLHZAZxjiBycYNPbjzfCmYlDF8WkQDIEC%2F41cbXBzG4WMCSor390idgUbbgtRNe3RURrVj7bwJE%3D"}],"group":"cf-nel","max_age":604800}',
          nel: '{"success_fraction":0,"report_to":"cf-nel","max_age":604800}',
          server: 'cloudflare',
          'cf-ray': '6df9243629a12aa5-ORD',
          'alt-svc': 'h3=":443"; ma=86400, h3-29=":443"; ma=86400'
        },
        config: {
          transitional: [Object],
          adapter: [Function: httpAdapter],
          transformRequest: [Array],
          transformResponse: [Array],
          timeout: 500000000,
          xsrfCookieName: 'XSRF-TOKEN',
          xsrfHeaderName: 'X-XSRF-TOKEN',
          maxContentLength: -1,
          maxBodyLength: -1,
          validateStatus: [Function: validateStatus],
          headers: [Object],
          method: 'get',
          url: 'https://app.zenserp.com/api/v2/search?apikey=xxx&q=Microsoft&location=10006,New%York,United%States&hl=en',
          data: undefined
        },
        request: <ref *1> ClientRequest {
          _events: [Object: null prototype],
          _eventsCount: 7,
          _maxListeners: undefined,
          outputData: [],
          outputSize: 0,
          writable: true,
          destroyed: false,
          _last: true,
          chunkedEncoding: false,
          shouldKeepAlive: false,
          maxRequestsOnConnectionReached: false,
          _defaultKeepAlive: true,
          useChunkedEncodingByDefault: false,
          sendDate: false,
          _removedConnection: false,
          _removedContLen: false,
          _removedTE: false,
          _contentLength: 0,
          _hasBody: true,
          _trailer: '',
          finished: true,
          _headerSent: true,
          _closed: false,
          socket: [TLSSocket],
          _header: 'GET /api/v2/search?apikey=xxxx&q=Microsoft&location=10006,New%York,United%States&hl=en HTTP/1.1\r\n' +
            'Accept: application/json, text/plain, */*\r\n' +
            'Content-Type: application/json\r\n' +
            'User-Agent: axios/0.25.0\r\n' +
            'Host: app.zenserp.com\r\n' +
            'Connection: close\r\n' +
            '\r\n',
          _keepAliveTimeout: 0,
          _onPendingData: [Function: nop],
          agent: [Agent],
          socketPath: undefined,
          method: 'GET',
          maxHeaderSize: undefined,
          insecureHTTPParser: undefined,
          path: '/api/v2/search?apikey=xxx&q=Microsoft&location=10006,New%York,United%States&hl=en',
          _ended: true,
          res: [IncomingMessage],
          aborted: false,
          timeoutCb: null,
          upgradeOrConnect: false,
          parser: null,
          maxHeadersCount: null,
          reusedSocket: false,
          host: 'app.zenserp.com',
          protocol: 'https:',
          _redirectable: [Writable],
          [Symbol(kCapture)]: false,
          [Symbol(kNeedDrain)]: false,
          [Symbol(corked)]: 0,
          [Symbol(kOutHeaders)]: [Object: null prototype]
        },
        data: { errors: [Array] }
      },
      isAxiosError: true,
      toJSON: [Function: toJSON]
    }
```

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Here's my package.json:

```
{
  "name": "functions",
  "description": "Cloud Functions for Firebase",
  "scripts": {
    "lint": "eslint",
    "serve": "firebase emulators:start --only functions",
    "shell": "firebase functions:shell",
    "start": "npm run shell",
    "deploy": "firebase deploy --only functions",
    "logs": "firebase functions:log"
  },
  "engines": {
    "node": "16"
  },
  "main": "index.js",
  "dependencies": {
    "@google-cloud/logging": "^9.6.9",
    "axios": "^0.25.0",
    "firebase-admin": "^10.0.2",
    "firebase-functions": "^3.18.0",
    "googleapis": "^92.0.0",
    "request": "^2.88.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "eslint": "^8.7.0",
    "eslint-config-google": "^0.14.0",
    "firebase-functions-test": "^0.3.3"
  },
  "private": true
}
```

Comment: If you are seeing no errors in the logs, what do you see in the logs?

Comment: @samthecodingman - I'm now seeing a large error output.

`Error: Request failed with status code 500
    at createError (/workspace/node_modules/axios/lib/core/createError.js:16:15)
    at settle (/workspace/node_modules/axios/lib/core/settle.js:17:12)
    at IncomingMessage.handleStreamEnd (/workspace/node_modules/axios/lib/adapters/http.js:312:11)
    at IncomingMessage.emit (node:events:402:35)
    at IncomingMessage.emit (node:domain:537:15)
    at endReadableNT (node:internal/streams/readable:1343:12)
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:83:21)...`

Comment: Hi @thebenCA, could you please include on your question a sample set of data received from your API for us to be able to reproduce the said issue.

Comment: @MarcAnthonyB - Absolutely. I just updated the original post to include a sample response from the Zenserp API.

Comment: Does `console.log("apiResponse = " + JSON.stringify(apiResponse));`prints what you expect (the entire response)?

Comment: @thebenCA, I tried to reproduce the error that you're encountering but I successfully deployed your code without having any error. I also tried to use REST API provided in [Zenserp PlayGround](https://app.zenserp.com/playground)  `https://app.zenserp.com/api/v2/search?apikey=YOUR-APIKEY&q=Pied%20Piper` and used personal API key but still successful. Can you check if you're getting data from the `console.log("apiResponse = " + JSON.stringify(apiResponse));` as @Renaud Tarnec said. And also, could you please also include the `package.json` on the question to further investigate the issue.

Comment: I am having a similar issue - Axios actually returns 200 response but the function finishes with 500. It can deploy and work as intended, but getting this error at the end of every execution.

Comment: @MarcAnthonyB - good callout. I just added my package.json to the question above.

Comment: I'm getting a new error message in GCP. Just added it to the post above.